# Women vs. Servants

Tags: women

In. birkas hashachar, men say שלא עשני עבד and שלא עשני אשה. Which halachos are different for an עבד and an אשה. I was thinking laws of taharas hamishpacha and candlelighting. Are there others?

Comment: Candle lighting is the same for everyone

Comment: Laws of marriage for one area that comes to mind.

Comment: @sabbahillel Which laws? Slaves can get married.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was thinking of the difference with eved cnaani and who they are allowed to marry. Also who an eved ivri can be partnered with while an eved.

Comment: @DoubleAA Slaves can get married, but they don’t have Kiddushin (Kiddushin 42b et. al.)

Comment: I’m not sure taharas mishpacha is a valid answer, only because it’s just not applicable to an eved. I do believe that a shifchah kena’anis does have Hilchos Niddah, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Sara. Your question seems to focus on just the general halachic rules. I don't see the connection of your focus to the *bracha*. If there is one, please edit your question to better explain it. If you're just asking about the halachic differences, maybe you should delete the first sentence.

Comment: @DanF This question seems to be based on a faulty assumption, that there are two brachos because they have different halachos. They therefore ask what are they, which are many. The proper understanding many have is there are different **mitzvah obligations** between them, and therefore one could ask what are they (see Shalom's answer). If this is what the OP meant, the question should be edited.

Answer (score 2):

Megillah reading: *they too were included in the miracle* applies to women, not to servants.

Comment: And several other positive commandments.

Comment: Source?........

Comment: @mevaqesh https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.689.2 but it seems the magen avrohom disagrees https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.689.2

Answer (score 0):

**a wife you need to feed**   ([ishut 1](http://www.chabad.org/952886/))

> When a man marries a woman, whether she is a virgin or a non-virgin, whether she is above the age of majority or a minor, and whether she was born Jewish, is a convert or a freed slave, he incurs ten responsibilities toward her ...
>   providing her with subsistence...

**a slave you do not** ([avadim 9-7](http://www.chabad.org/1363819))

> A master may tell his Canaanite slave: "Work for me, but I will not provide you with sustenance," and the slave must instead, go and beg from door to door and derive his sustenance from charity. For the Jews are obligated to support the slaves that live among them.

---

by the way, the brochos are different not because of different halochos
see
https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.4a.11
https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.43b.59?with=Rashi
http://daattorah.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/rav-moshe-feinstein-man-is-more-of.html

Comment: I don't think think the OP meant halachos between a man and a woman vs a man and a slave. You can see that from the examples they gave; they meant a woman vs a slave